# Specific scaffold bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
________________
|_______| img  |
|_______|______|
|______________|
```

How can I make this with bootstrap columns? Silly question, I know, but thanks anyways everyone!

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail? Have you looked at the bootstrap documentation? Do you have any sample code? Can you show your work in a jsfiddle or bootply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

**HTML**

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="row two">
        </div>
        <div class="row one1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 two2">
        your image here
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row three">
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.two {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.three {
  background-color: skyblue;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.one1 {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.two2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/DTcHh/15144/)